# How to join same named sublist elements and add an ID variable

Tags: r, list, purrr

Suppose we have a list like this:

```
l <- list()
l[[1]] <- list()
l[[2]] <- list()
l[[3]] <- list()

names(l) <- c("A", "B", "C")

l[[1]][[1]] <- data.frame(6)
l[[1]][[2]] <- data.frame(3)
l[[1]][[3]] <- data.frame(8)
l[[1]][[4]] <- data.frame(7)

l[[2]][[1]] <- data.frame(5)
l[[2]][[2]] <- data.frame(4)
l[[2]][[3]] <- data.frame(7)
l[[2]][[4]] <- data.frame(9)

l[[3]][[1]] <- data.frame(1)
l[[3]][[2]] <- data.frame(6)
l[[3]][[3]] <- data.frame(2)
l[[3]][[4]] <- data.frame(8)

names(l[[1]]) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")
names(l[[2]]) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")
names(l[[3]]) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")
```

I want to create a list `l2` which contains 4 elements: `aa`, `bb`, `cc` and `dd`. Each of these elements would be the dataframe which would contain the values of `aa`, `bb`, `cc` and `dd` from list `l` and also an ID variable which would indicate if the element came from the `A`, `B` or `C` element of list `l`. So if we built the end result from scratch, it would look like this:

```
l2 <- list()

l2[[1]] <- data.frame(Value = c(6, 5, 1), ID = c("A", "B", "C"))
l2[[2]] <- data.frame(Value = c(3, 4, 6), ID = c("A", "B", "C"))
l2[[3]] <- data.frame(Value = c(8, 7, 2), ID = c("A", "B", "C"))
l2[[4]] <- data.frame(Value = c(7, 9, 8), ID = c("A", "B", "C"))

names(l2) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd")
```

However, I cannot build it from scratch, but instead I must "reshape" `l` to `l2`. What is the best way to do this? Preferred solution is in `purrr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is `transpose()`. You could set `.id = "ID"` in the inner `map_dfr()` to create a new column `ID` recording the names of sub-lists where each value comes when row-binding each element together.

```r
library(purrr)

l %>%
  transpose() %>%
  map(~ map_dfr(.x, set_names, "Value", .id = "ID"))
```

###### Output

```
$aa
  ID Value
1  A     6
2  B     5
3  C     1

$bb
  ID Value
1  A     3
2  B     4
3  C     6

$cc
  ID Value
1  A     8
2  B     7
3  C     2

$dd
  ID Value
1  A     7
2  B     9
3  C     8
```